# ImageAugmentation:Input must be >= 2-d

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, pickle, tflearn

I tried loading a pickle file for a cnn but error message on augmentation shows "ValueError: Input must be >= 2-d."

```
            from tflearn.data_augmentation import ImageAugmentation
            # load dataset

            X,Y,X_test,Y_test=pickle.load(open("train.pkl","rb"))

            Y = to_categorical(Y, 2)
            Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, 2)

            # Real-time data preprocessing
            img_prep = ImagePreprocessing()
            img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center()
            img_prep.add_featurewise_stdnorm()

            # Real-time data augmentation
            img_aug = ImageAugmentation()
            img_aug.add_random_flip_leftright()
            img_aug.add_random_rotation(max_angle=25.)

            # Convolutional network building
            network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3],
                                 data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                                 data_augmentation=img_aug)
```

I wonder if it is because my Y and Y_test are only in 0 or 1, which makes it 1 dimensional. If so, I would appreciate any input in helping to write the proper .pkl file. The code for the label is below

```
            img_label[i] = numpy.asarray(name, dtype='float64')
```

and name is the folder name to store the pictures, 0 or 1. I tried renaming the folders to [0,1] and [1,0] or 0,1 and 1,0. Both triggered a datatype error message.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: We are facing the same issue, have you found a solution? It will be really appreciated.